# Changing default Access to a function in a php file under the subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to run my `activeIndex()` function in `GuestsController.php` file under a subdirectory as the first default page when the user enters the url.

For this reason, I have written such a script in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/controllers/GuestsController.php/.*
RewriteRule ^/mvc/(.*) /controllers/GuestsController.php?method=$actionList?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And my `GuestsController.php` file is:

```
<?php

class GuestsController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {       
        echo "start";
        sleep(1);       
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../views/guests/index.php' );
    }

    public function actionList()
    {
        $guests = Guests::findAll();

        echo json_encode( $guests );
    }
}
```

I still could not manage to achieve my goal.

How I should modify .htaccess file to run actionIndex() function directly?

Thanks,

Comment: Look at this, this may give you an idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019611/php-assigning-a-default-function-to-a-class

Comment: Your `GuestsController.php` file simply contains a class definition - it doesn't contain any runable code (unless this is not shown)? Your `RewriteRule` substitution seems to be malformed (you have two `?`)? Where is your .htaccess file located? The `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` pattern appear to reference two very different URL paths so it's difficult to see how this would match?

Comment: so how can I modify my .htaccess?

Comment: It's not just a matter of changing .htaccess (which is incorrect as w3d noted) but you aren't calling anything in your script as it appears. Check out the link I mentioned.